# Calculate CID for a file without uploading to IPFS in C#

Tags: c#, ipfs

I've wrote in the past an AWS Lambda that uses Nodejs to calculate the CID , using the following npm package: ```pure-ipfs-only-hash``. For a revision on the lambda function we're using we would switch to .NET Core 6 lambda so I wish to know if there're a package that I can use that calculates the CID passing a file or a stream, without the need to upload to IPFS
Thanks

Comment: So far the only offline solutions I could find are either running the JS implementation in .NET using Jint, or converting the Go implementation to C# using go2cs. Both require effort.